Missing implementation (but help message says I have implemented it)
I'm writing a tonic middleware to load application state into a gRPC handler, and I cannot get my app to serve with the middleware layer
I've double-checked the types and looked at many examples and I can't tell what I've gotten wrong in my implementation. Not only that, but the help message in the compiler error seems to indicate that I have implemented it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Full error on compilation:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `RegistryApplicationStateMiddleware<Routes>: Service<http::request::Request<tonic::transport::Body>>` is not satisfied
  --> registry/src/main.rs:39:6
   |
39 |     .serve(addr)
   |      ^^^^^ the trait `Service<http::request::Request<tonic::transport::Body>>` is not implemented for `RegistryApplicationStateMiddleware<Routes>`
   |
   = help: the trait `Service<http::Request<tonic::transport::Body>>` is implemented for `RegistryApplicationStateMiddleware<S>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `registry` (bin "registry") due to 1 previous error

Note the help message indicates the trait is implemented for a generic version of the middleware?? but is somehow not matching Routes...
middleware.rs
use std::{convert::Infallible, task::{Context, Poll}};

use data_access::db::ConnectionPool;
use http::Response;
use tonic::{body::BoxBody, server::NamedService};
use tower_service::Service;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
pub struct RegistryApplicationState {
    pub pool: ConnectionPool,
}


#[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
pub struct RegistryApplicationStateLayer {
    pub pool: ConnectionPool,
}

impl<S> tower_layer::Layer<S> for RegistryApplicationStateLayer {
    type Service = RegistryApplicationStateMiddleware<S>;

    fn layer(&self, service: S) -> Self::Service {
        RegistryApplicationStateMiddleware {
            inner: service,
            pool: self.pool.clone(),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct RegistryApplicationStateMiddleware<S> {
    inner: S,
    pub pool: ConnectionPool,
}


impl<S> Service<http::request::Request<tonic::transport::Body>> for RegistryApplicationStateMiddleware<S>
where
S: Service<http::request::Request<tonic::transport::Body>, Response = Response<BoxBody>, Error = Infallible>
    + NamedService 
    + Clone
    + Send + 'static,
    S::Future: Send + 'static,
    S::Error: Into<Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send + Sync>> + Send,
{
    type Response = S::Response;
    type Error = S::Error;
    type Future = futures::future::BoxFuture<'static, Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>;

    fn poll_ready(&mut self, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        self.inner.poll_ready(cx)
    }

    fn call(&mut self, mut req: http::request::Request<tonic::transport::Body>) -> Self::Future {
        // This is necessary because tonic internally uses `tower::buffer::Buffer`.
        // See https://github.com/tower-rs/tower/issues/547#issuecomment-767629149
        // for details on why this is necessary
        let clone = self.inner.clone();
        let mut inner = std::mem::replace(&mut self.inner, clone);

        req.extensions_mut().insert(RegistryApplicationState {
            pool: self.pool.clone(),
        });

        Box::pin(async move {
            // Do extra async work here...
            let response = inner.call(req).await?;

            Ok(response)
        })
    }
}

main.rs
use middleware::RegistryApplicationStateLayer;
use tonic::transport::Server;

use client::registry_service_server::RegistryServiceServer;
use server::DemoClient;


use data_access::db::ConnectionPool;

pub mod client;
mod middleware;
pub mod server;

mod store_proto {
  include!("client.rs");

  pub(crate) const FILE_DESCRIPTOR_SET: &[u8] =
    tonic::include_file_descriptor_set!("store_descriptor");
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
  dotenv::dotenv().ok();
  let addr = "127.0.0.1:9001".parse()?;
  let demo_registry_service = DemoClient::default();

  let reflection_service = tonic_reflection::server::Builder::configure()
    .register_encoded_file_descriptor_set(store_proto::FILE_DESCRIPTOR_SET)
    .build()
    .unwrap();

    let pool = ConnectionPool::default();


  Server::builder()
    .layer(RegistryApplicationStateLayer { pool })
    .add_service(RegistryServiceServer::new(demo_registry_service))
    .add_service(reflection_service)
    .serve(addr)
    .await?;
  Ok(())
}

Another note, this is what the Router service implementation looks like in the tonic lib, which I tried to emulate in my implementation:
/// A [`Service`] router.
#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone)]
pub struct Routes {
    router: axum::Router,
}

impl Routes {
    pub(crate) fn new<S>(svc: S) -> Self
    where
        S: Service<Request<Body>, Response = Response<BoxBody>, Error = Infallible>
            + NamedService
            + Clone
            + Send
            + 'static,
        S::Future: Send + 'static,
        S::Error: Into<crate::Error> + Send,
    {
        let router = axum::Router::new().fallback(unimplemented);
        Self { router }.add_service(svc)
    }

    pub(crate) fn add_service<S>(mut self, svc: S) -> Self
    where
        S: Service<Request<Body>, Response = Response<BoxBody>, Error = Infallible>
            + NamedService
            + Clone
            + Send
            + 'static,
        S::Future: Send + 'static,
        S::Error: Into<crate::Error> + Send,
    {
        let svc = svc.map_response(|res| res.map(axum::body::boxed));
        self.router = self
            .router
            .route_service(&format!("/{}/*rest", S::NAME), svc);
        self
    }

    pub(crate) fn prepare(self) -> Self {
        Self {
            // this makes axum perform update some internals of the router that improves perf
            // see https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/routing/struct.Router.html#a-note-about-performance
            router: self.router.with_state(()),
        }
    }
}

Lastly, here's my Cargo.toml file
[package]
name = "registry"
version = "0.1.0"
build = "build.rs"
edition = "2021"
publish = false

[dependencies]
axum = { version = "0.7.5", features = [ "json" ] }
clap = { version = "4.1.4", features = ["derive"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
futures = "0.3"
http = "1.1.0"
hyper = "1.2.0"
prost = "0.11"
tokio = { version = "1.37", features = ["full"] }
tokio-stream = { version = "0.1", features = ["net"] }
tonic = "0.8"
tonic-reflection = "0.6.0"
tower-http = { version = "0.5.0", features = ["trace"] }
tower-layer = "0.3.2"
tower-request-id = "0.3.0"
tower-service = "0.3.2"
tracing = "0.1.37"
tracing-subscriber = "0.3.16"
bytes = "1.6.0"

[build-dependencies]
tonic-build = "0.8"

[dev-dependencies]
uuid = { version = "1.2.2", features = ["v4", "fast-rng"] }
futures-util = "0.3.25"
anyhow = "1"




Routes probably doesn't meet the litany of bounds you have in the where clause on that trait impl.

Maybe because the Service impl has type Response = Response<UnsyncBoxBody<Bytes, Status>> and type Error = Box<dyn Error + Sync + Send> unlike your bound

What's the versions of your dependencies? Looks like you've got two tower_services involved.

@Cerberus what do you mean two tower_services ? It looks like I have 0.3.2 installed everywhere
As for the Service implementation/bounds, doesn't the following mean we are taking the types off of the S generic?
type Response = S::Response;
type Error = S::Error;

@PitaJ yeah good reminder that loosening the bounds should increase the likelihood of matching routes, but I've like trimmed it down as much as I can without breaking the implementation and it still seems dissatisfied

I mean, one version is the one explicitly set in Cargo.toml, another - pulled transitively by some other dependency (likely axum). I'll look into it tomorrow, if no one steps up before.

ugh, the problem was hyper. Tonic doesn't support hyper 1.0 yet

Always double-check your dependencies, kids. The problem was I had hyper 1.0 installed and Tonic doesn't support hyper 1.0 yet. Here's the working (compiling) middleware with hyper = "0.14.28"

use std::task::{Context, Poll};

use axum::extract::FromRef;
use data_access::db::Pool;
use hyper::body::Body;
use tonic::body::BoxBody;
use tower_service::Service;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
pub struct RegistryApplicationState {
  pub pool: Pool,
}

impl FromRef<RegistryApplicationState> for Pool {
  fn from_ref(app_state: &RegistryApplicationState) -> Pool {
    app_state.pool.clone()
  }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Default)]
pub struct RegistryApplicationStateLayer {
  pub pool: Pool,
}

impl<S> tower_layer::Layer<S> for RegistryApplicationStateLayer {
  type Service = RegistryApplicationStateMiddleware<S>;

  fn layer(&self, service: S) -> Self::Service {
    RegistryApplicationStateMiddleware {
      inner: service,
      pool: self.pool.clone(),
    }
  }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct RegistryApplicationStateMiddleware<S> {
  inner: S,
  pub pool: Pool,
}

impl<S> Service<hyper::Request<Body>>
  for RegistryApplicationStateMiddleware<S>
  where
      S: Service<hyper::Request<Body>, Response = hyper::Response<BoxBody>> + Clone + Send + 'static,
      S::Future: Send + 'static,
  {
  type Response = S::Response;
  type Error = S::Error;
  type Future = futures::future::BoxFuture<'static, Result<Self::Response, Self::Error>>;

  fn poll_ready(&mut self, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
    self.inner.poll_ready(cx)
  }

  fn call(&mut self, mut req: hyper::Request<Body>) -> Self::Future {
    // This is necessary because tonic internally uses `tower::buffer::Buffer`.
    // See https://github.com/tower-rs/tower/issues/547#issuecomment-767629149
    // for details on why this is necessary
    let clone = self.inner.clone();
    let mut inner = std::mem::replace(&mut self.inner, clone);

    req.extensions_mut().insert(RegistryApplicationState {
      pool: self.pool.clone(),
    });

    Box::pin(async move {
      // Do extra async work here...
      let response = inner.call(req).await?;

      Ok(response)
    })
  }
}



